# Method to decode partial JPEG byte array in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, jpeg, bitmapfactory

I'm working on an Android app where I have a byte array of a JPEG image and need to display it.  Currently, I'm decoding it in Android with this code:

```java
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
ImageView imageDisplay = findViewById(R.id.image_display);
imageDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

This works great, if I have the full image.  However, if I take the byte array and chop off, say, the final 25% of it, `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` returns `null`.  According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory#decodeByteArray(byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int)), the method `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` returns:

> The decoded bitmap, or null if the image could not be decoded.

This surprises me because I thought partial JPEGs *could* be decoded.  As an experiment, I opened a JPEG in a hex editor and chopped it down to 75%, 50%, and 25% of its original size, and, in all cases, Windows was still able to show the image (I was able to open each image in Paint.NET too!)

[image: standard JPEG example]

If I saved the image as a "progressive" JPEG, the performance was even better!  Below, the **partial-25.jpg** file is only the first quarter of the original file's bytes, but it displays quite well.  If you zoom in, there is less detail, but it's pretty good!

[image: progressive JPEG example]

I'm looking for this same behavior in Android.  When encountering a JPEG byte array that ends prematurely, I want to draw whatever I have so far.

**Is there some way to get `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` to give me this behavior, or is there another Android included method that could do so?  If not, I'm willing to use a library for it.**

(The reason I'm doing this is because the image data is actually arriving very slowly (think *bytes per second* slowly), and I'd like to draw it as it comes in, rather than waiting until the end to draw the whole thing.)